# Protocol buffer with node.js - failed to generate js from .proto

Tags: javascript, node.js, protocol-buffers, proto, protoc

Trying to use [google protocol buffer](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/) in my node.js web server with [this documentation](https://github.com/google/protobuf/tree/master/js).

When running the following command:

```
protoc --js_out=import_style=commonjs,binary: ServiceMessage.proto
```

I received:

```
--js_out: : Unknown option: import_style
```

Any suggestions?

Cheers,
Itay

Comment: @zangw You suggest a different module, I'll give it a try and update. Thanks!

Comment: Per this [discussion](https://github.com/google/protobuf/pull/1215), this feature is added recently, does protoc you used is latest verion?

Comment: @zangw libprotoc 3.0.0

Comment: Version 3.0.0 is released in 2015-12-30, you may get the latest codes of protobuf...

Comment: I've download the version from here: https://github.com/google/protobuf/releases it's the newest beta :-(

Comment: Per this [commit history](https://github.com/google/protobuf/commit/24c5424be5b220d8d4575e4262ee5d6ad9417959), it is changed at Feb 20, I think you should update your codes with latest one.

Comment: @zangw That's work! I've download the source, configure / make / sudo make install and use the '.' as you suggested. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per this [discussion line](https://github.com/google/protobuf/pull/1215), the `js_out` is added recently and merge at Feb 20, you may updated your protoc with latest codes from protobuf.