# Error: Cannot find module 'google-protobuf'

Tags: javascript, node.js, protocol-buffers, proto

Following to my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36156425/protocol-buffer-with-node-js-failed-to-generate-js-from-proto), I'm trying to use protocol buffers in node.js. I've generated `ServiceMessage_pb.js` from my `ServiceMessage.proto`, and add the following code:

```
var messages = require('./ServiceMessage_pb');
```

Now I'm getting the following error in my node log:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'google-protobuf'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:325:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:276:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/aii/ws/ServiceMessage_pb.js:8:12)
    at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
```

Any suggestions how to solve this?

Thanks

Comment: `npm.org` does not list any module named `google-protobuf`. Probably it has been moved, renamed or is published elsewhere.

Comment: @S.D there is https://www.npmjs.com/package/protobuf  **This is a fork of http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-for-node/**

Comment: There is a require statement at line 8 of  ServiceMessage_pb.js that specifically requires google-protobuf. It looks like the generator of this file uses google-protobuf, while actual module is protobuf.

Comment: `npm.org` homepage of the National Association of Pastoral Musicians, true, no protos there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install the module with npm:

```
npm install --save protobuf
```

Then require it this way:

```
var my_protobuff = require ("protobuf");
```

Comment: Can you look at my prev question (link above) - I've download the source code, compiled it & install.. I don't think I should do it again. I'll try your second suggestion about the require and update soon.. 10x

Comment: you don't need to compile the source code yourself. Just use npm

Comment: can you post the directory structure of your project?

Comment: I think it all unstable because I'm using v3.0.0 beta... I'll try to downgrade to 2.6 - thanks anyway..

Comment: `WARNING` This is NOT the official google package. See other answers.

Answer (score 6):

```
    npm i google-protobuf
```

I run into so many problem installing just "protobuf" !

Also the official protobuf javascript package is "google-protobuf":
https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-protobuf