# Node cannot find installed package

Tags: node.js, protocol-buffers, package.json

I have a simple `nodejs` `client` that uses `grpc` and `protobuf` to talk to a `cpp` `grpc` server.
My `package.json` contains the `required` packages:

```
"dependencies": {
       "google-protobuf": "^3.9.1",
       "grpc-web": "^1.0.6",
       "webpack": "^4.39.2",
      "webpack-cli": "^3.3.7"
    }
```

I ran `npm install` and all the modules were installed in locally `node_modules`.

My client in in the same path as `node_modules` but when I launch it, I get an error saying that it cannot find the protobuf module.

**From client.js:**

```
var messages  = require('../../messages/proto/output/work_pb.js');
var services  = require('../../messages/proto/output/work_grpc_web_pb.js');
var grpc      = require('grpc');
```

**Running the client:**

```
node client.js
```

```
Error: Cannot find module 'google-protobuf'
Require stack:
- /home/work/messages/proto/output/work_pb.js
- /home/work/frontend/web/client.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:713:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:618:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:771:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:68:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/radu/work/admass/messages/proto/output/work_pb.js:11:12)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:868:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:879:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:731:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:644:12)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:771:19) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    '/home/work/messages/proto/output/work_pb.js',
    '/home/work/frontend/web/client.js
```

Comment: I think you need to install `protobuf` https://stackoverflow.com/a/36173766/8608146

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up adding the node module inside `'../../messages/` and removing it from pace where the proto files are being referenced, as to avoid conflicts.

Answer (score 0):

Removing the entire node_modules folder and re-installing will work:

```
rm -rf node_modules
npm install
```

Comment: My issue is related to the fact that I have the `../../messages/proto/output/work_pb.js` in some other path, and I think node tries to find the modules there. I need to tell node to look in the current dir.